# PHP calling function within a class

Tags: php, plugin-development, oop, plugin-json-api

I'm writing my own php class and I have multiple functions within the class. Something like this:

```
class JSON_API_Hello_Controller {

    public function test_cat(){
        global $json_api;

        $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array( 'cat' => 3));
        return $this->posts_object_result_bycat($posts);
    }

    public function test_cat1() {
        global $json_api;

        $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array( 'cat' => 2));
        return $this->posts_object_result_bycat($posts);
    }

    protected function posts_object_result_bycat($posts) {
        global $wp_query;

        return array(
            'count' => count($posts),
            'pages' => (int) $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'posts' => $posts
        );
    }

    public function mix_cat(){

        $first_cat = $this->test_cat();
        $second_cat = $this->test_cat1();
        $json1 = json_decode($first_cat , true);
        $json2 = json_decode($second_cat, true);
        $final_array = array_merge($json1, $json2);
        // Finally encode the result back to JSON.
        $final_json = json_encode($final_array);
    }

}
```

I tried something like this. I want to call the `test_cat()` and `test_cat1()` function in other function like `mix_cat()` inside the same class. Both function (`test_cat()` & `test_cat1()`) return the json object. Both return json object will be join in `mix_cat()` function. Please suggest me How can I call the `testcat()` & `test_cat1()` function in `mix_cat()` and join the result of both function in `mix_cat()` function.

Comment: What doesn't work in what you tried ?

Comment: It is more a PHP question, not really the right forum with topic WordPress. But maybe you use `wp_json_encode()`, then is more WP relevant ;)

Comment: @Antoine Guillien thanks for your reply first  i want to call the both function    [test_cat() & test_cat1()] in another function mix_cat() function. when i call the bothe function like this  public function mix_cat(){
        $first_cat = $this->test_cat();
        $second_cat = $this->test_cat1(); print_r($second_cat); }  and check the  data of both function then i found  first variable ($first_cat) contain the data of test_cat() function but second variable ($second_cat) did't contain the data of  test_cat1() function. please try to suggest me how  i can display the both function data.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge this two json objects via `array_merge`. But you must decode before to a array. You have this inside your example, below as single source function. This should get the merged json object.

A example function, usable for your `mix_cat()`method.

```
function mergeToJSON( $obj1, $obj2 ) {

    $json1 = $this->test_cat();
    $json2 = $this->test_cat1();

    if ( $json1 === FALSE || $json2 === FALSE ) {
        return;
    }

    $array1 = json_decode( $json1, TRUE );
    $array2 = json_decode( $json2, TRUE );
    $data = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );

    return json_encode( $data );
}
```

Comment: Isn't it what he did in his example ? (exept for the false verification and the return)

Comment: I add only the check for the verification.